# iOS Theos Calling Different Hooked Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos

I have got the following method that I have hooked into

```
%hook Request

- (_Bool)sendData:(id)arg1 time:(int)arg2 {
    _Bool r = %orig;

    return r;
};
```

I am trying to call this method from sendData:

```
- (_Bool)enable:(const char *)arg1 p:(int)arg2 {
    _Bool r = %orig;
    return r;
};
```

I have tried these:

```
[self enable:"test" p:12];
error: instance method '-enable' not found

[self performSelector:@selector(enable:"test":123)];
error: expected ')'

[[%c(Request) sharedInstance] enable:"test" p:123];
error: class method '+sharedInstance' not found
```

Help please. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `[self enable:"test" p:12];` works in Objective-C. What is the full error text that is displayed?

Comment: [self enable:"test" p:80]; error: instance method '-enable:p:' not found
      (return type defaults to 'id') [-Werror,-Wobjc-method-access]

Comment: Do I need to do #import "Request.h"??

Comment: Is `enable:p:` in the same class as `sendData:time:`?

Comment: Yep same class. Request Class

Comment: And you're calling `[self enable:"test" p:12]` inside of `sendData:time:`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70725/discussion-between-d123-and-ian-macdonald).